# Disable minor mode when keys not in it's keymap are pressed

Tags: key-bindings, minor-mode

I was using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/88828/921319) to implement line duplication in emacs and decided to bind it to `C-c d` and it works without problems

What would be cooler though is if I can use `C-c d` do duplicate a line and then be able to make further duplications of this line by simply typing `d`. If I want 4 duplications, then the call would be `C-c d`, `d`, `d`, `d`.

What's the best way to achieve this? I assumed it would be activating a minor mode with `C-c d` that, when it starts, duplicates a line and then has the `duplicate-line` function bound to "d" in it's keymap.

The problem with this is that you have to disable the minor mode when a key is pressed that is not in it's keymap. Can this be done?

Or am I approaching this problem completely wrong?

Comment: Wow, two great answers from zck and glucas! I'm going with the one from zck though because it keeps me from *having* to add another dependency to my emacs config. That having been said though, I think hydra looks really cool and I could see it becoming a standard package in my config anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `set-transient-map`. First, make a sparse keymap with the binding you want for repetition:

```
(setq duplicate-line-keymap
      (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
        (define-key map (kbd "d") #'my-duplicate-line)
        map))
```

Then, you can make your function, and at the end, call `set-transient-map`, and give it the keymap:

```
(defun my-duplicate-line ()
  (interactive)
  (duplicate-line)
  (set-transient-map duplicate-line-keymap))
```

Now, when you call `#'my-duplicate-line`, if you press "d" again, it'll repeat the call to `#'my-duplicate-line`, but if you press anything else, it'll do that behavior instead. You can put a message in the minibuffer to indicate what's going on:

```
(defun my-duplicate-line ()
  (interactive)
  (duplicate-line)
  (message "press d to duplicate again!")
  (set-transient-map duplicate-line-keymap))
```

Answer (score 4):

This is exactly the use case for the [`hydra`](https://github.com/abo-abo/hydra) package, which you can install via `package-install` from melpa.

For example:

```
(defhydra hydra-duplicate-line ()
  "duplicate line"
  ("d" duplicate-line nil))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c d") 'hydra-duplicate-line/duplicate-line)
```

This will bind `C-c d` to a command that will duplicate the current line and leave in a "temporary mode" where pressing d will duplicate the line again, and any other key will exit the hydra and do its usual function.

Hydra can do lots more, but this is a good place to start!

Comment: Note that `hydra` is creating transient maps using the mechanism described in @zck's answer. If this is a one-off scenario then you may not want to install a whole new package. That said, hydra makes it very convenient to create some quite sophisticated "temporary modes".